# How is it that Golden Experience Requiem is the ONLY Sentient Stand that we seen and why haven't there been any others like Chariot Requiem?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Basically Golden Experience Requiem (GER) is the only stand that is seen to talk by itself without the user talking through their stand(and no Star Platinum doesn't count because Jotaro uses it to talk to the user of Dark Blue Moon and the user of Strength and it wasn't Star Platinum being sentient). Chariot Requiem has no user and it's a Requiem evolution and yet it isn't sentient (or at least hasn't shown any). The closest thing we have to having a sentient stand after Part 5 is Part 6's White Snake. White Snake can move seperately from it's user and manifest in a certain range (20 meters). But Enrico still has to talk through his stand so I wouldn't count that. So back to the question; Are there any sentient stands other than GER? Could the lack of sentient stands after Part 5 be an "Araki forgot" moment or is it intentional? These things have been on my mind for a long time so thank you to whoever answers this question for me and please tell me if there are any sentient stands that I missed in any of the anime or manga.

Answer (score 0):

Empress, Anubis, Echoes Act 3, Cheap Trick, Stray Cat, Spice Girl (temporarily), Foo Fighters, the green baby 'stand' and Yo Yo Ma, are sentient as they act not by the command of the user, or are the user themselves. You could argue SCR and Notorious B.I.G are sentient, but speechless. You could argue that High Priestess, Red Hot Chili Pepper, Osiris, Atum, Boy II Man, Bad Company, Harvest, The Lock, Marilyn Manson, and Ebony Devil are semi-sentient, as they aren't being strictly controlled by their user, and seem to have some sort of judgement of their own. Thoth, Burning Down the House,  Highway to Hell, Dragon's Dream, Rolling Stones and Superbug could also be considered sentient in the sense that the user does not control them.

I might have missed some stands still.

Disclaimer: I have not read part 7 and 8.

Comment: You could also argue shear heart attack is semi-sentient as it is deployed by Kira but not directly controlled it is more of an autonomous attack the nearest heat source kinda deal